# Audit trigger 91plus: setting up with proper role?

Tags: postgresql, audit

One of the solutions available for auditing in PostgreSQL is **Audit trigger 91plus**.

- [wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)
- [github page](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger)

There is a section in the wiki that is confusing to me:

> Changes by the table owner and superusers are tracked, but can be trivially tampered with.

Ok... I am not sure if this means someone with access rights to the database via console or GUI or if this means something else...

> If you want this audit log to be trustworthy, your app should run with a role that has at most USAGE to the audit schema and SELECT rights to audit.logged_actions. Most importantly, your app must not connect with a superuser role and must not own the tables it uses. Create your app's schema with a different user to the one your app runs as, and GRANT your app the minimum rights it needs.

Apologies for my lack of understanding: I don't understand the picture here. If I have a web app using a PostgreSQL db, what exactly are the dangers if I use Audit trigger 91plus without the different role the wiki talks about?

Answer (score 0):

If I own the table (the owner is the user that created the table) or am a [superuser](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html), I can modify and drop triggers on a table.

This makes it trivial to tamper with trigger based auditing.

For good security, it is a good idea to use an application user different from the object owner, and of course not a superuser.